# How to add several asp.net application on IIS with same host and port/

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-server

Hi I simply want to do:

localhost:80/ASPnetpplication1
localhost:80/ASPnetApplication2
localhost:80/ASPnetApplication3
localhost:80/ASPnetApplicationN

but I have no idea how to configure this on IIS.
All of the answers point to using bindings but when I add bindings it sends me to aspnetapplication/ as a hostname instead of this path in the url.
Please help.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis You are supposed to add applications to a single site. "All of the answers" you read in fact do not apply to what you attempt to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I knwo, we could add multiple application in same IIS web site like below:

[image]

[image]

Then we could access different site in the same url as below:

[image]